# Paginating a linq query which uses OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to return a list of a certain entity grouped by a certain property, ordered descending by timestamp and paginated (using Skip and Take). What I got is this:

```
container.CoinMessageSet.Where(
                c => c.MessageState != MessageStateType.Closed &&
                     (c.DonorOperator.OperatorCode.Equals("opcode") ||
                      c.RecipientOperator.OperatorCode.Equals("opcode"))
                ).OrderByDescending(c => c.TimeStamp)
                 .GroupBy(c => c.Reference).Skip(x).Take(100);
```

Upon execution I got the Exception:

```
The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. 
The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.
```

...I called OrderBy() (albeit Descending) and I called it before Skip()! What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't ordered the groups; you need to do that before you can page. For example:

```
.GroupBy(c => c.Reference).OrderBy(grp => grp.Key).Skip(x).Take(100);
```

(you can also substitute `OrderByDescending` if you want the groups in reverse order)

Also: since you are grouping, the order in the original data is largely meaningless; you could probably remove the `OrderByDescending(c => c.TimeStamp)`.

So net result:

```
var query = container.CoinMessageSet.Where(
            c => c.MessageState != MessageStateType.Closed &&
                 (c.DonorOperator.OperatorCode.Equals("opcode") ||
                  c.RecipientOperator.OperatorCode.Equals("opcode"))
            ).GroupBy(c => c.Reference).OrderBy(grp => grp.Key)
             .Skip(x).Take(100);
```

or possibly:

```
var query = (from c in container.CoinMessageSet
             where c.MessageState != MessageStateType.Closed &&
                  (c.DonorOperator.OperatorCode == "opcode" ||
                   c.RecipientOperator.OperatorCode == "opcode")
             group c by c.Reference into grp
             orderby grp.Key
             select grp).Skip(x).Take(100);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the original issue, and realising I have a new one ;) (namely 'I have to order by TimeStamp but this is largely useless due to GroupBy)

Answer (score 2):

It is most probably because of the `GroupBy` after the `OrderByDescending`.

I think you can try:

```
container.CoinMessageSet.Where(
                c => c.MessageState != MessageStateType.Closed &&
                     (c.DonorOperator.OperatorCode.Equals("opcode") ||
                      c.RecipientOperator.OperatorCode.Equals("opcode"))
                ).OrderByDescending(c => c.TimeStamp)
                 .GroupBy(c => c.Reference).OrderByDescending(c = > c.Key).Skip(x).Take(100);
```